# What statistical test is this?

Tags: t-test

This is an excerpt from a paper I was reading: "Product type and evaluations were used to predict the number of control, explained action, and explained reaction sentences chosen. Evaluations were a significant covariate for control (t(1, 156)= -2.52, p < .01) and explained action sentences (t(1, 156)= 4.03, p < .01)."

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question. But I can't figure out what statistical test the author is reporting here- since there are 2 numbers in the df section I don't think this is a normal t-test. Could you guys help, please?

Comment: May be $1$ is a type of alternative hypothesis? One tail here.

Comment: Also $1$ can the number of groups minus one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked paper "Predictability and Helpfulness in
Online Reviews: The Role of Explained
Actions and Reactions" by 
SARAH G. MOORE and think that it is typo. 
Correct text should be

> Evaluations were a significant covariate for control (t(156)= -2.52, p < .01) and explained action sentences (t(156)= 4.03, p < .01).

Comment: Thank you for looking at the source. I am trying to understand what the statement "evaluations were a significant covariate" means. Since evaluations are on a 7 point Likert scale, I'm wondering how the author reports a t-test for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at the paper, but suggest you compare the 156 DF number to the reported sample size. If this is a t test, then the 156 should be n - 1, where n is sample size. So sample size should be 157. If n is 158, then maybe this was an F test with k = 1 predictor and DF (k, n - k - 1). 156 seems like a lot of DF for a t test.

Comment: n is 159, but your comment makes sense!